# SQL query returning empty and I can't figure out why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have this complicated query that technically works, but recently the "developer_" part of it changed from required to optional. Now when that particular data is missing, the query returns empty.

```
    $sql = "SELECT    a.*,
                      b.title AS manufacturer_title,
                      b.slug AS manufacturer_slug,
                      b.url AS manufacturer_url,
                      c.fname AS manufacturer_logo,
                      d.title AS region_title,
                      e.title AS game_title,
                      e.slug AS game_slug,
                      f.title AS developer_title,
                      f.slug AS developer_slug,
                      f.url AS developer_url,
                      g.fname AS developer_logo,
                      h.title AS exclusive_title,
                      h.slug AS exclusive_slug,
                      h.url AS exclusive_url,
                      i.fname AS exclusive_logo,
                      j.title AS edition_title,
                      k.title AS edition_parent_title
            FROM      catalog_items AS a
            JOIN      catalog_franchises AS b ON a.manufacturer_id = b.franchise_id
            LEFT JOIN catalog_images AS c ON b.logo_id = c.img_id
            JOIN      catalog_regions AS d ON a.region_id = d.region_id
            JOIN      catalog_franchises AS e ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
            JOIN      catalog_franchises AS f ON a.developer_id = f.franchise_id
            LEFT JOIN catalog_images AS g ON f.logo_id = g.img_id
            LEFT JOIN catalog_franchises AS h ON a.exclusive_id = h.franchise_id
            LEFT JOIN catalog_images AS i ON h.logo_id = i.img_id
            LEFT JOIN catalog_editions AS j ON a.edition_id = j.edition_id
            LEFT JOIN catalog_editions AS k ON j.parent_id = k.edition_id
            WHERE     a.item_id = :item_id
                      AND a.valid = TRUE
                      AND b.valid = TRUE
                      AND (c.valid = TRUE OR c.fname IS NULL)
                      AND d.valid = TRUE
                      AND e.valid = TRUE
                      AND f.valid = TRUE
                      AND (g.valid = TRUE OR g.fname IS NULL)
                      AND (h.valid = TRUE OR h.title IS NULL)
                      AND (i.valid = TRUE OR i.fname IS NULL)
                      AND (j.valid = TRUE OR j.title IS NULL)
                      AND (k.valid = TRUE OR k.title IS NULL)
            GROUP BY  a.item_id";
```

I have tried modifying `AND f.valid = TRUE` to various things:

`AND (f.valid = TRUE OR f.title IS NULL)`

`AND (f.valid = TRUE OR a.developer_id IS NULL)`

But nothing seems to do the trick. What do I need to modify so that all references to "developer_" can be optional?

Comment: What a great example showing why *not* to use arbitrary letters for table aliases.  Use abbreviations of the table names!

Comment: I think you need to change it to a LEFT Join - from the documentation `In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other) `

Comment: Why not simply the problem

Comment: And note that these are all inner joins (sort of)

Comment: Specifically, JOIN to f needs to change to LEFT JOIN, and the check for f.valid needs one of the `OR ... IS NULL` conditions.

Comment: @Strawberry `these are all inner joins` - that's kind of what i meant, as in the Join is working as an inner join rather than a left join - so it needs changing to allow the empty result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tidy up your JOIN and WHERE stuff and use one more LEFT JOIN. By putting the `x.valid = TRUE` items in the ON conditions things get a little cleaner in the `OR ... IS NULL` department.

And to keep rows in the resultset where `catalog_franchises.franchise_id` doesn't match any `catalog_items.developer_id` change out your JOIN for a LEFT JOIN.

```sql
SELECT      a.*, b.many columns, c.many columns ... etc ...
  FROM      catalog_items AS a
  JOIN      catalog_franchises AS b     ON a.manufacturer_id = b.franchise_id
                                       AND b.valid = TRUE
  LEFT JOIN catalog_images AS c         ON b.logo_id = c.img_id
                                       AND c.valid = TRUE
  JOIN      catalog_regions AS d        ON a.region_id = d.region_id
                                       AND d.valid = TRUE
  JOIN      catalog_franchises AS e     ON a.game_id = e.franchise_id
                                       AND e.valid = TRUE
  /* use LEFT JOIN on this next line to allow developer_id to not match */
  LEFT JOIN catalog_franchises AS f     ON a.developer_id = f.franchise_id
                                       AND f.valid = TRUE
  LEFT JOIN catalog_images AS g         ON f.logo_id = g.img_id
                                       AND g.valid = TRUE
  ... etc etc etc  ...
  WHERE a.item_id = :item_id
    AND a.valid = TRUE
  GROUP BY  a.item_id  /* this wrongly chooses arbitrary values from aliases b-k */
```

You're misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). It may cause some confusion in your result set when you start getting results.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` appears to be what I was overlooking, thank you for your help